# How do I tag a sentence with the Brown or CoNLL2000 tagger / chunker?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm a nltk and Python newbie, but I'd like to tag a sentence using the Brown or CoNLL2000 tagger instead of the default pos_tag tagger.

Right now I'm simply doing:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

sentence = "The Turtles fight Shredder."
tags = pos_tag(sentence.split())
```

which yields the result

```
>>> tags
[('The', 'DT'), ('Turtles', 'NNP'), ('fight', 'NN'), ('Shredder.', 'NNP')]
```

As you can see 'fight' is incorrectly labelled as 'NN'. I noticed on this page http://text-processing.com/demo/tag/, the CoNLL2000 tagger got a better result for me. For the same sentence it shows:

> Tagged Text
>
> The/DT Turtles/NNS fight/VB Shredder/NN ./.
>
> Phrases and Named Entities
>
> NP:
>   The/DT Turtles/NNS
>   VP:
>   fight/VB
>   NP:
>   Shredder/NN

I'm not sure how to use those taggers though. I feel like it's something simple, but I couldn't find an example searching Google.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in Name Entity chunker in NLTK:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> sent = "The turtles fight Shredder."
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))
[('The', 'DT'), ('turtles', 'NNS'), ('fight', 'VBD'), ('Shredder', 'NNP'), ('.', '.')]
>>> ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)))
Tree('S', [('The', 'DT'), ('turtles', 'NNS'), ('fight', 'VBD'), Tree('PERSON', [('Shredder', 'NNP')]), ('.', '.')])
>>> for i in ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))):
...     print i
... 
('The', 'DT')
('turtles', 'NNS')
('fight', 'VBD')
(PERSON Shredder/NNP)
('.', '.')
```

But it has some quirks, e.g. there's a difference when a noun chunk is capitalized:

```
>>> sent = "The ninja turtles fight Shredder."
>>> for i in ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))):
...     print i
... 
('The', 'DT')
('ninja', 'NN')
('turtles', 'NNS')
('fight', 'VBD')
(PERSON Shredder/NNP)
('.', '.')
>>> sent = "The Ninja Turtles fight Shredder."
>>> for i in ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))):
...     print i
... 
('The', 'DT')
(ORGANIZATION Ninja/NNP Turtles/NNP)
('fight', 'NN')
('Shredder', 'NNP')
('.', '.')
```

Comment: I did not down vote you. I thought your answer was good, but I still get different results than you. 
`pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))`
...gives me...
`[('The', 'DT'), ('Turtles', 'NNP'), ('fight', 'NN'), ('Shredder', 'NNP'), ('.', '.')]` ...and... `ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)))` ...gives me... `Tree('S', [('The', 'DT'), Tree('GPE', [('Turtles', 'NNP')]), ('fight', 'NN'), ('Shredder', 'NNP'), ('.', '.')])`

Comment: Yes. Updating did work. Weird, I only downloaded it a few days ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did try using the [TextBlob package](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/), which got me much better results too.

My code looks like this:

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> from textblob_aptagger import PerceptronTagger

>>> sentence = "The Turtles fight Shredder."
>>> blob = TextBlob(sentence, pos_tagger=PerceptronTagger())
>>> blob.tags
[('The', u'DT'), ('Turtles', u'NNPS'), ('fight', u'VBD'), ('Shredder', u'NNP')]
```

So now "fight" is correctly labeled a "verb" and "Turtles" a plural proper noun. The downside to using this package is that it's a bit slow.  But I might be able to optimize my code to fix that. :)